# error: cannot find symbol variable parent error: cannot find symbol variable position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I keep getting these two errors i tried adding dependency and installing android support repository but this error is not solved. I tried invalidate catche and restarting project but that too didn't helped. Tried everything i could hope you guys could help

[this is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAYQL.png)

here is my code

```
package ankittx.com.forsale.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import ankittx.com.forsale.R;
import ankittx.com.forsale.models.Post;

public class PostListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PostListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private static final String TAG = "PostListAdapter";
private static final int NUM_GRID_COLUMNS = 3;

private ArrayList<Post> mPosts;
private Context mContext;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView mPostImage;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mPostImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        int gridWidth = 
mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
        mPostImage.setMaxHeight(imageWidth);
        mPostImage.setMaxWidth(imageWidth);

    }
}

public PostListAdapter(Context mContext ,ArrayList<Post> mPosts) {
    this.mPosts = mPosts;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_view_post, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage(mPosts.get(position).getImage(), viewHolder.mPostImage);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Check all arguments name when you copy/pasted code from some where else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `int i` parameter  use `int position`  in parameter.

Change your method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage(mPosts.get(position).getImage(), viewHolder.mPostImage);

}
```

To

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage(mPosts.get(position).getImage(), viewHolder.mPostImage);

}
```

**And**

Instead of `parent` parameter  use `viewGroup` as parent viewGroup.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_view_post, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_view_post, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, can you help me with this  problem 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324625/i-am-getting-gettextbeforecursor-on-inactive-inputconnection-and-other-warning

Comment: Yes will check.